# how to access the name or url content from this array in php?

Tags: php, json

How can I show this data inside an HTML table in PHP?

I convert the JSON to an array using the "json_decode" function.

Just wanted to know a method to convert the array to an HTML table or fetch specific details such as name or URL.

Thanks

```
[
  {
    "trends": [
      {
        "name": "#GiftAGamer",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23GiftAGamer",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "%23GiftAGamer",
        "tweet_volume": null
      },
      {
        "name": "#TransDayOfRemembrance",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23TransDayOfRemembrance",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "%23TransDayOfRemembrance",
        "tweet_volume": 45852
      },
      {
        "name": "Mourão",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=Mour%C3%A3o",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "Mour%C3%A3o",
        "tweet_volume": 12614
      },
      {
        "name": "Taysom Hill",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Taysom+Hill%22",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "%22Taysom+Hill%22",
        "tweet_volume": 20311
      },
      {
        "name": "Geraldo",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=Geraldo",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "Geraldo",
        "tweet_volume": 30166
      }
    ],
    "as_of": "2020-11-20T19:37:52Z",
    "created_at": "2020-11-19T14:15:43Z",
    "locations": [
      {
        "name": "Worldwide",
        "woeid": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Why not use a common loop, as for all other arrays? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

First you want to understand the structure. The JSON you pasted is an array with exactly one (1) element, which is an object with the keys `trends`, `as_of`, `created_at` and `locations`.

In PHP you can access an element in an array via the index (starting at 0) `$array[index]`, eg. `$array[0]`.

An object on the other hand is accessible via the method syntax, which in PHP in a single arrow `->`, eg. `$object->attribute`.

So, in order to get the name of the first element in "trends", you have to access each array and/or object from the start.

```
<?php
$json = json_decode($string); // json string you posted
$object = $json[0]; // get the first element of the overall array
$trends = $object->trends; // get the trends attribute of the first object, which is an array again
$first_trend = $trends[0]; // array can be accessed via the index again.
$first_name = $first_trend->name; // a trend is an object again with attributes name, url, promoted_content, etc.
```

Of course you want to access this data in an dynamic way, which is where loops come in handy. PHP offers `foreach`, which can iterate over array elements and also object attributes. Take a read: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

With this, you can iterate all trends like this

```
foreach($trends as $trend) {
  echo $trend->name;
}
```

You of course can wrap HTML (eg. a table) around.

```
<?php
echo "<table>";
$json = json_decode($string);
$trends = $json[0]->trends;
foreach($trends as $trend) {
  echo "<tr>"; // new table row

  foreach($trend as $key => $value) {
    // this iterates over all attributes of trend
    echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
  }

  echo "</tr>"; // close table row
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

This is an example of a loop inside another loop. The outer loop iterates all trends, the inner loop iterates the attributes of the current trend.